# Set wrapper height equal in all browsers

Tags: html, css, height, wrapper

I have a wrapper and I need to set it's height equal in all browsers.

How do I do that?
Actually I have tried by using min-height and height:100% but it's not working.

This is how it actually shows in different browsers:

[image]
Here is my CSS:

```
    body
{
    background: #99CCFF;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

    #wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    margin:-20px auto;
    width:auto;
    height:450px;
    background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the CSS causing the layouts in your screenshot? `height:450px` should be pretty consistent throughout all browsers...

Comment: @Ptriek-I agreee with you but how to get rid of this?As Daff mentioned to set the html height that too did not work well.

Comment: there must be something else in your code causing the problem, if i past your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/bD8PW/) all browsers render consistently at 450px height...

Comment: Yeah sorry that was not it. It could have something to do with the negative margins though.

Comment: @Daff-Might be.I am checking it.

Comment: @Daff-I have checked by removing it but it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kiran

You should get rid of your negative margin, first of all. If you see one browser has a layout issue, you can deal with that later using a [conditional css](http://www.conditional-css.com/) statement in your header, and a separate css file.

But to answer your main question. make sure you always use margin:0; and padding:0; when doing initial layout. this will take away a lot of layout bugs in the very beginning. Some versions of IE don't conform to web standards, so there isn't much you can do sometimes, other than workarounds. (i.e. conditional css)

Have a look at this sample page a created for you.
I took away you position:relative, and added the float and display properties, as well as changed your margins and padding to zero on BOTH body and #wrapper. I also changed the width of your wrapper from auto, to 100%.

http://www.albatrossfonts.com/heightcss/wrapperHeight.html

I used white as a background color for the wrapper as well, since I don't have access to your image.

Here's the code:

```
body
{
    background: #99CCFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: @jhilgert00-Thanks for the info.I am really thankful to you that you have solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ Each browser treats padding, margin and other properties differently.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
```